# Multiple Elementor "Group_Control_Background" control label is not working

Tags: elementor

I need 3 background group control on Elementor custom widget. So, I am using this:

```
$this->add_group_control(
    \Elementor\Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
    [
        'name' => 'background_active',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Background Active', 'plugin-name' ),
        'types' => [ 'classic', 'gradient', 'video' ],
        'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .navigate-master ul li a.active',
        'default' => esc_html__( '#ffb200' , 'plugin-name' ),
        'condition' => [
            'nm_nm_title' => '',
        ],
    ]
);

$this->add_group_control(
    \Elementor\Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
    [
        'name' => 'background',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Background', 'plugin-name' ),
        'types' => [ 'classic', 'gradient', 'video' ],
        'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .navigate-master ul li a',
        'default' => esc_html__( '#ffb200' , 'plugin-name' ),
        'condition' => [
            'nm_nm_title' => '',
        ],
    ]
);

$this->add_group_control(
    \Elementor\Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
    [
        'name' => 'background_hover',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Background Hover', 'plugin-name' ),
        'types' => [ 'classic', 'gradient', 'video' ],
        'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .navigate-master ul li a:hover',
        'default' => esc_html__( 'yellow' , 'plugin-name' ),
        'condition' => [
            'nm_nm_title' => '',
        ],
    ]
);
```

You can see that I have used a unique name and label but I can't see the different label on the widget sidebar.

Can you tell me why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

// You Can set color & change label name

```
$this->add_group_control(
    Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
    [
        'name' => 'content_background',
        'label' => esc_html__('Background', 'pixel-gallery'),
        'types' => ['classic', 'gradient'],
        'exclude' => ['image'],
        'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}}',
        'fields_options' => [
            'background' => [
                'label' => esc_html__('Custom Background', 'pixel-gallery'),
                'default' => 'classic',
            ],
            'color' => [
                'default' => '#fff',
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Group_Control_Background** control of **Elementor**. And this control supports Custom label as well.

```
$this->add_group_control(
Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
[
    'name'     => 'slider_overlay_hover',
    'label'    => esc_html__('Background', 'elementor-addons'),
    'types'    => ['classic', 'gradient', 'video'],
    'fields_options' => [
        'background' => [
            'label' => 'New Label Here...'
        ],
    ],
    'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}}',
]
```

);

Have a great time!